# 'Object variable not set' error on a simple code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro on "PERSONAL.XLSB" in excel-vba.
I am retrieving a range from one of the open workbook and later I want to loop through that range.

```
Sub test()

Dim ran_a As Range

ran_a = Workbooks("TWE-Tool_V05_Modified.xlsm").Worksheets("Frame").Range("A1:AZ2")
end sub
```

However it keeps showing me the

> Run time error '91'
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign an object to a object variable you must use `Set` statement.

Try thus:
`Set ran_a = Workbooks("TWE-Tool_V05_Modified.xlsm").Worksheets("Frame").Range("A1:AZ2")`

More information: [Set Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b85bc00.aspx)